# Taking output of union in different column in postgres

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql

I am working for a dialer company and we have a call history table in which we have different column.

Now I want to take one output in which I can calculate:

**total number of outbound call which is connected**

```
Select count(*) 
from call_history 
where system_disposition = 'CONNECTED' and call_type = 'OUTBOUND'
```

**total AMD detected by System**

```
Select count(*) 
from call_history 
where system_disposition = 'CONNECTED'
```

**Total AMD detected by AGent**

```
Select count(*) 
from call_history 
system_disposition='CONNECTED' and call_id in (
    select call_id 
    from udh 
    where disposition_code = 'Answering machine'
)
```

Now if I am using union command all result coming in one column and using cross join is giving repetitive output i.e. limit 2 giving output of each entry two time.

Please help me in making a single query which can tell me as:

*Total outbound conected | AMD by SYSTEM  | AMD by AGent | Leakage as (AMD Agent/(Total)*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We will help you solve problems, but not write code for you. The idea is to try yourself, and get help with the hard stuff. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information

Answer (score 0):

you can union the results and select each result in an individual column like this :

```
Select sum(r1) as result1, sum(r2) as redult2, sum(r3) as result3 from(
Select count(*) as r1, 0 as r2,0 as r3 from call_history where system_disposition='CONNECTED' and call_type='OUTBOUND'
Union
Select 0 as r1,count(*) as r2, 0 as r3 from call_history where system_disposition='CONNECTED')
Union
Select 0 as r1, 0 as r2,count(*) as r3 from call_history system_disposition='CONNECTED' and call_id in (select call_id from udh where disposition_code='Answering machine')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Postgresql

```
select *, "AMD by AGent"::numeric/"Total outbound conected" as "Leakage"
from (
    select
        count(call_type = 'OUTBOUND' or null) as "Total outbound conected",
        count(*) as "AMD by SYSTEM",
        count(exists (
            select 1
            from udh
            where
                disposition_code = 'Answering machine' and
                call_id = call_history.call_id
        ) or null) as "AMD by AGent"
    from call_history
    where system_disposition = 'CONNECTED'
) s
```

In 9.4+ there is the [aggregate filter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)